# Building Hadoop with Maven Error

Tags: maven, hadoop

When I try to build hadoop using:

mvn install -e -DskipTests

It always throw the following error:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/xiu/myGit/hadoop2/hadoop-mr1-project/hadoop-mr1/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/security/TestTokenCache.java:[153,4] getDelegationTokenSecretManager() is not public in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem; cannot be accessed from outside package
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MR1 ................................. FAILURE [3.144s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MR1 Examples ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MR1 Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.353s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 18 11:01:30 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/100M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project hadoop-mr1: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/xiu/myGit/hadoop2/hadoop-mr1-project/hadoop-mr1/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/security/TestTokenCache.java:[153,4] getDelegationTokenSecretManager() is not public in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem; cannot be accessed from outside package
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have tried clean and reinstall different versions of maven with no luck. Any expert knows what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Maven compiler plugin complaining that `getDelegationTokenSecretManager()` method in Hadoop `FSNameSystem` is not accessible due to method visibility i.e. it's not public:

```
[ERROR] /home/xiu/myGit/hadoop2/hadoop-mr1-project/hadoop-mr1/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/security/TestTokenCache.java:[153,4] getDelegationTokenSecretManager() is not public in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem; cannot be accessed from outside package
[INFO] 1 error
```

I would suggest you to check on your Hadoop version defined in your pom.xml, and double check that the method is really accessible in the Hadoop version JavaDoc.

Answer (score 2):

I came across same problem during hadoop 2.2.0 source code building. During "mvn install -DskipTests" this error came in "Hadoop Auth" Folder.
From somewhere(i dont remember from where) i came to know that there is one missing dependency in pom.xml of this Hadoop Auth  folder

dependency is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I added this dependency and again tried "mvn install -DskipTests". My error resolved.

You just try to add this dependency in pom.xml of "APACHE Hadoop MR1". May ur error will resolve

Comment: This dependency seems to also be required without `-DskipTests` (I'm running `mvn package -Pdist,native -Dtar`)